# Are there differences between the HEV and PHEV Niro that would make hitch mounting different between them?

Tags: kia, trailer-hitch, part-interchange, plug-in-hybrid, niro

I would like to add a trailer hitch to my 2023 Kia Niro PHEV in order to use a bicycle rack that I already own.

When I search for the part on a typical retail site, there are no results, but if I search for either "2023 Niro" or "2023 Niro EV", there is a hitch on offer (and it's the same for both). Other than this obvious hint from the retailer, is there any reason to expect that it *wouldn't* fit on a PHEV as well?

(For example, maybe the exhaust is routed differently, or the mounting holes are different or nonexistent).

Comment: Perhaps their database does not distinguish between the various models.  Perhaps the plug-in EV, typically with a larger battery pack, changed stuff in the back. From the pictures of a Niro or Niro EV hitch you may be able to figure out where mounting points should be, and go see if they are there?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does -- they have a fitment tool that recognizes all three separately.

Comment: I suppose that leaves you to figure out if the mounting points exist, or to stop by a possible supplier in person to ask.

Comment: @SortofDamocles - It recognized them separately, but is the part number the same?

Comment: They are the same part # for the Niro and Niro EV.